# Difference between `cluster-allow-reads-when-down` and `cluster-require-full-coverage` in redis v6

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

As per the documentation, below are the expalanations: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redis/redis/6.0/redis.conf

```
# By default Redis Cluster nodes stop accepting queries if they detect there
# is at least an hash slot uncovered (no available node is serving it).
# This way if the cluster is partially down (for example a range of hash slots
# are no longer covered) all the cluster becomes, eventually, unavailable.
# It automatically returns available as soon as all the slots are covered again.
#
# However sometimes you want the subset of the cluster which is working,
# to continue to accept queries for the part of the key space that is still
# covered. In order to do so, just set the cluster-require-full-coverage
# option to no.
#
# cluster-require-full-coverage yes


# This option, when set to yes, allows nodes to serve read traffic while the
# the cluster is in a down state, as long as it believes it owns the slots. 
#
# This is useful for two cases.  The first case is for when an application 
# doesn't require consistency of data during node failures or network partitions.
# One example of this is a cache, where as long as the node has the data it
# should be able to serve it. 
#
# The second use case is for configurations that don't meet the recommended  
# three shards but want to enable cluster mode and scale later. A 
# master outage in a 1 or 2 shard configuration causes a read/write outage to the
# entire cluster without this option set, with it set there is only a write outage.
# Without a quorum of masters, slot ownership will not change automatically. 
#
# cluster-allow-reads-when-down no
```

However, I am yet to understand if a master-slave pair goes down in redis cluster, which of this config will come into effect which allows me to continue to accept reads..?
Is it `cluster-require-full-coverage no` or `cluster-allow-reads-when-down yes`

Comment: @antirez could you please help ^^

Comment: The former will fit your needs.

Comment: @ItamarHaber if i keep `cluster-allow-reads-when-down yes` and `cluster-require-full-coverage yes` the cluster is stable able to support reads even when a master-slave pair goes down. so don't know where to draw the line in terms of end-user behavior between both the options.

Answer (score 0):

I checked both options.

When **cluster-require-full-coverage yes** (default) and **cluster-allow-reads-when-down yes** and the cluster is down (down one or more masters), the only command get available (excluding keys on the down master), set is not with message `(error) CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down and only accepts read commands`.

When **cluster-require-full-coverage no** and **cluster-allow-reads-when-down no** the first option is powerest and the both commands get and set are available (excluding keys on the down master).